# Firebug Command Line History

Tags: firebug

[In Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/commandline), the command line  of JavaScript console maintains its own history of executed expressions and so, you can easily go back and execute an expression again.

This is true only when the history is not too long because otherwise there is no way to get the entry you want.

For reproduce the problem just try to push the run button several times after inserting some code.

So the solution could be to claen the history of the JavaScript command line. Is it possible?
Or there are other ways to fix this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue. I disabled then enabled firebug, then closed and restarted Firefox. The history is now gone.

EDIT: disabling the add-on was not needed. Just restart the browser and the list clears.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to clear the Command History.

To do this, click the little red box with the triangle in it.  It's in the bottom right corner of FireBug.
This will give you a menu with these options

```
Run    Clear   Copy    History
```

Click Clear.  All set!

Comment: thanks but maybe I was not clear...I will attach a picture to show you what I want.

Comment: oh.  I don't think that's possible.  BUT, you could write your own extension for FireBug.  See here http://www.phpied.com/firefox-firebug-extension-creator-wizard/  and here http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug-tutorial/extending-firebug-hello-world-part-i/  for some good head starts.

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the page seemed to work for my needs. It didn't seem to clear the firebug history, but it did clear variable declarations and assignments and such.